# how to classify groups based on the individuals who compose them?

Tags: r, classification

Here's my problem : I have a database of individuals (1 individual per row). Each individual belongs to a household (indicated by the variable `ID_household`) and is of a certain age (variable `age`). What I want to do is to create a new column `type` that defines the type of household based on the composition of individuals who form the same household :

- If there are 2 adults (two people of more than 18 years old), the type variable takes the value "couple" ;
- If there are 1 adult and at least 1 minor with a minimum age difference of 15 years = "single parent family" ;
- If there are 2 adults and at least 1 minor with a minimum age difference of 15 years = "couple with children" ;
- If there is a single person = "single person".

Here's the script to import the data.
`ID_household` and `age` are the original columns. `type` is the column I want to create, but I don't know how to do :

```
data <- data.frame(ID_household = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11),
           age = c(31, 29, 36, 24, 34, 42, 19, 39, 6, 9, 42, 4, 6, 29, 34, 41, 12, 51, 26, 27, 1, 3),
           type = c("couple", "couple", "single person", "couple", "couple", "single person", "single person",
                    "single parent family", "single parent family", "single parent family", "single person",
                    "couple with children", "couple with children", "couple with children", "couple with children", 
                    "single parent family", "single parent family", "single person", "couple with children",
                    "couple with children", "couple with children", "couple with children"))

data
   ID_household age                 type
1             1  31               couple
2             1  29               couple
3             2  36        single person
4             3  24               couple
5             3  34               couple
6             4  42        single person
7             5  19        single person
8             6  39 single parent family
9             6   6 single parent family
10            6   9 single parent family
11            7  42        single person
12            8   4 couple with children
13            8   6 couple with children
14            8  29 couple with children
15            8  34 couple with children
16            9  41 single parent family
17            9  12 single parent family
18           10  51        single person
19           11  26 couple with children
20           11  27 couple with children
21           11   1 couple with children
22           11   3 couple with children
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it by creating the variables regarding kids, adults and age-differences and using `case_when()`.  In the code below, I am making `type2` to compare with the `type` variable in your dataset:

```
data <- data %>% 
  group_by(ID_household) %>% 
  mutate(n_adult = sum(age > 18), 
         n_kids = sum(age <= 18),
         min_adult_age  = min(age[which(age > 18)]), 
         max_kid_age = ifelse(n_kids > 0, max(age[which(age <= 18)]), 0),  
         age_diff = min_adult_age - max_kid_age, 
         type2 = case_when(
            n_adult == 2 & n_kids > 0 & age_diff >= 15 ~ "couple with children", 
            n_adult == 1 & n_kids > 0 & age_diff >= 15 ~ "single parent family", 
            n_adult == 2 & n_kids == 0 ~ "couple",
            n_adult == 1 & n_kids == 0 ~ "single person", 
            TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>% 
  select(-(n_adult:age_diff))

all(data$type == data$type2)           
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I didn't see how to do it with dplyr, but in fact it's possible, very ingenious! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R way with `ave`.

```
type <- with(data, ave(age, ID_household, FUN = \(x){
  if(length(x) < 2) {
    "single person"
  } else if(length(x) == 2L && all(x >= 18)) {
    "couple"
  } else if(sum(x >= 18) == 1){
    "single parent family"
  } else "couple with children"
}))

identical(data$type, type)
#[1] TRUE
```